# Xcode test target can't access framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am integrating IBM's Digital analytics library to my project without Cocoapods, following this documentation https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/tutorials/getting-started-digital-analytics-sdk-ios/ . It worked great, however my test target is not able to access the DigitalAnalytics class from the framework I added to the application. I am getting "use of unresolved identifier Digital Analytics" when I run my tests.

Should we do anything special to make this framework available to test targets as well? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your target for tests did not include the pods.  Here is an example : I have considered a pod for SQLCipher.  Have all your pods within this block.  This is for ease of use.  Replace <> and <> with the corresponding targets for your project.

```rb
def shared_pods
  pod 'SQLCipher', '~>4.1.0'    
end

target '<<TargeName>>' do
    shared_pods
end

target '<<TargetNameForTests>>' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Comment: like I mentioned I am not using cocoapods

Comment: my bad.  did you add the framework to the test target and still you are not able to access it

Comment: I am assuming your code is in swift.  Is there a  Bridging header in the target of your tests ?